# kendo-ui slider different steps for the first range

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, slider, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm using a Kendo-UI slider to allow the user to dynamically select a specific percentage. Selecting 0% makes no sense in my particular application. The problem is that I need the slider to show the ticks on multiple of 10 values (except on the first value/tick). In order to achieve this I need to set the minimum value to 0 and have the large step from 10 to 10:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Slider()
    .Name("sliderPercentage")
    .DragHandleTitle("Select")
    .Min(0)
    .Max(100)
    .SmallStep(1)
    .LargeStep(10)
    .Value(80)
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:500px;" })
)
```

This however allows the user to select the 0% value which can be confusing. What I really need is a way of setting the minimum value to 1 and the first large step to 9, so that the ticks are shown like this: 1  10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90  100. How can I achieve this?